# Converting a web app into an embeddable <script> tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I just did a proof of concept/demo for a web app idea I had but that idea needs to be embedded on pages to work properly.

I'm now done with the development of the demo but now I have to tweak it so it works within a  tag on any websites.

The question here is:
How do I achieve this without breaking up the main website's stylesheets and javascript?

It's a node.js/socket.io/angularjs/bootstrap based app for your information.

I basically have a small HTML file, a few css and js files and that's all. Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: It's a button located on the bottom right corner of the page that will embed the script. So I doubt an iframe would do the job for that case (it's a lot of position absolute stuff too) thanks!

Comment: @TomShreds What does `position: absolute;` have to do with anything?

Comment: I cannot position something outside of an iframe, am I right? The. If I need to pop something up right in the middle of the website I cannot use an iframe as wide and tall as the document. That'd be silly.

Comment: @Benjamin, would you mind telling me why the heck are you removing "Thanks" in my question? I mean, I'm grateful to those who are willing to help me and I really believe that it's an important part of a question and the way I'm asking it, in my opinion. Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: There's quite a lengthy discussion that has been ongoing on meta about "thanks" and other similar greetings/salutations. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have is a `script` tag, and you want to inject UI/HTML/etc. into the host page, that means that an `iframe` approach may not be what you want (although you could possibly do a hybrid approach). So, there are a number of things that you'd need to do.

For one, I'd suggest you look into the general concept of a bookmarklet. While it's not exactly what you want, it's very similar. The problems of creating a bookmarklet will be very similar:

1. You'll need to isolate your JavaScript dependencies. For example, you can't load a version of a library that breaks the host page. jQuery for example, can be loaded without it taking over the `$` symbol globally. But, not all libraries support that.
2. Any styles you use would also need to be carefully managed so as to not cause issues on the host page. You can load styles dynamically, but loading something like Bootstrap is likely going to cause problems on most pages that aren't using the exact same version you need.
3. You'll want your core Javascript file to load quickly and do as much async work as possible as to not affect the overall page load time (unless your functionality is necessary). You'll want to review content like [this](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/) from Steve Souders.
4. You could load your UI via a web service or you could construct it locally.
5. If you don't want to use JSONP style requests, you'll need to investigate enabling [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

You could use an iframe and [PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) to show some UI without needing to do complex wrapping/remapping of the various application dependencies that you have. PostMessage would allow you to send messages to tell the listening iFrame "what to do" at any given point, while the code that is running in the host page could move/manipulate the iframe into position. A number of popular embedded APIs have used this technique over the years. I think DropBox was using it for example.

Comment: Thanks for such informative answer ! I have one worry though. The service I'm working on works kinda like getsatiafaction it has a button on the page and pops a non modal dialog in which they can chat. But I need it to be totally transparent like if it was really integrated in the page. My worry is that with an iframe I'd still need to find a way to use bootstrap right? That's my worry right now, I need to use angularjs and bootstrap and that's where I'm totally lost. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: An iframe would be isolated and you could use bootstrap inside the iframe. For anything outside, no, you couldn't use Bootstrap unless you customized it signficantly. You can make an iframe transparent, but would you really want that anyway? (As your "styles" may not look good on an arbitrary web site design).

Comment: I could go with a transparent iframe but I personally hate the thought of doing it that way. Maybe I could make my own style instead of using bootstrap but i would still need to use angularjs which I guess I can just async load it. Do you know any code example I could look at to wrap my head around this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Code example for what? As suggested, look for tutorials creating bookmarklets (here's one: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/). They need to do something **very** similar in general.